# having trouble with radio buttons passing on value

Tags: javascript, radio-button

ok so I got thrown a project and I have limited js experience. I'm trying to make a script that takes the results of some radio button clicks and text inputs and it puts together a IP for them to be directed to.
my code kinda works lol, but I know there has to be cleaner way.
when I cant remember how I tried doing it but it was involving document.getelementbyname("loc).value but it was returning undefined.. now that Im trying to do the same thing with the "port" radios I want to do it right. sorry if I messed this post up.

```
<label><input type="radio"   name="loc" value="16" onclick= "clt();" />Carolinas</label><br>
<label><input type="radio"   name="loc" value="17" onclick= "geo();"/>Georgia</label><br>
<label><input type="radio"   name="loc" value="18" onclick= "sxw();"/>Xpress</label><br><br>


<label><input type="number" placeholder="Store Number" id="thirdOct" /> </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="90"/>Port 90</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="91"/>Port 91</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="92"/>Port 92</label>
<br>    
<input type="submit" class="fsSubmitButton" value="Connect" onclick="makeIp();" />



var ipAdd;
var sNum = "0";
var int = [":", 81 ];

// had to go this route for a value, because when I try to call by document.getElementByName("loc") in my makeIp function it returns undefined for the value of "loc" 





function clt()
{sNum = "16";}


function geo() 
{sNum = "17";}

function sxw ()
{ sNum = "18";}

function makeIp() 
{
var storeN = document.getElementById("thirdOct").value;
var octThree;
if (storeN >= 300 && storeN <= 399) {

            octThree = storeN.slice(-2);
        if (octThree < 10) { 
            octThree = storeN.slice(-1);
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]  ,"_blank");
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] );
                            }
        else { 
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]  ,"_blank");
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]  );
                                    }       

                            }
else {

        if (storeN >= 300) { 
            octThree = storeN.slice(-2);

            if (octThree < 10) { octThree = storeN.slice(-1);
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");

                                }

            else {
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
                        }
            }
        else { octThree = storeN; 
        var ipAdd    = "http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1] ;    
             console.log(ipAdd);
        window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
        console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");

       }
   }
}
```

so I found a possible solution using the following code to replace the functions I had called clt, geo, and sxw....

```
var radios = document.getElementsByName('genderS');

for (var i = 0, length = radios.length; i < length; i++) {
if (radios[i].checked) {
    // do whatever you want with the checked radio
    alert(radios[i].value);

    // only one radio can be logically checked, don't check the rest
    break;
}
}
```

Comment: You may use `document.querySelector('[name="genderS"]:checked').value;` to get the value of checked radio button.

Answer (score 0):

I am posting this in the answer field so I can show you code, but I'm not quite sure that this is your answer since you didn't post all the pertinent original code.

I've modified your code to get rid of the inline HTML event handlers and consolidated redundant code. I've also corrected several errors where you were comparing a string value against a number:

```
  storeN >= 300 && storeN <= 399
```

and

```
  octThree < 10
```

```js
var rads = document.querySelectorAll(input[type=radio]);
for(var i = 0; i < rads.length; ++i){
  rads[i].addEventListener("click", setVal);
}

var btn = document.querySelector(input[type=button]);
btn.addEventListener("click", makeIp);

var sNum = 0;
var int = [":", 81 ];
var ipAdd = null;

function setVal(){
    sNum = parseInt(this.value, 10);
}

function makeIp() {
  var strNum = document.getElementById("thirdOct").value;
  var storeNum = parseInt(strNum, 10);
  var octThree = null;
  
  if (storeNum >= 300 && storeNum <= 399) {
        octThree = parseInt(strNum.slice(-2), 10);
        if (octThree < 10) { 
            octThree = strNum.slice(-1);
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]);
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]);
                            }
        else { 
            window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]);
            console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0]);
        }       

  } else {

        if (storeNum >= 300) { 
            parseInt(strNum.slice(-2), 10);

            if (octThree < 10) { 
              octThree = storeN.slice(-1);
              window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
              console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
            } else {
              window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
              console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
            }
  } else { 
    octThree = storeN; 
    var ipAdd    = "http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1] ;    
    console.log(ipAdd);
    window.open("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
    console.log("http://172." + sNum + "." + octThree + ".65" + int[0] + int[1],"_blank");
  }
}
```

```html
<label><input type="radio" name="loc" value="16">Carolinas</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="loc" value="17">Georgia</label><br>
<label><input type="radio" name="loc" value="18">Xpress</label><br><br>

<label><input type="number" placeholder="Store Number" id="thirdOct" /> </label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="90">Port 90</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="91">Port 91</label>
<label><input type="radio" name="cwPort" value="92">Port 92</label>
<br>    
<input type="button" class="fsSubmitButton" value="Connect">
```